# How to read encrypted and gzipped blob data from u-sql

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I would like to read file from a blob that is first compressed (gz) and then encrypted. The encryption done using Azure SDK when file uploaded to Blob (BlobEncryptionPolicy passed to [CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn434979.aspx) method).

There blob file have .gz extension so U-SQL trying to decompress but fails as the file is encrypted.

1. Is it possible to set my u-sql script to handle the decompression automatically same as done by Azure SDK (for instance by [CloudBlockBlob.BeginDownloadToStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt423217.aspx))?
2. If not and I need to use custom extractor, how can I prevent the U-SQL from trying to decompress the stream automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The decompression is automatically triggered by the ".gz" extension. So you would have to rename the document. Also, please note that you cannot call to any external resource to decrypt from within your user-code. You will have to pass all keys as parameters to the custom extractor.

Finally, if you store the data in ADLS, you get transparent encryption of the data and it makes the whole thing a lot easier. Why are you storing it in Windows Azure Blob Storage instead?