# Decompress .gz file in Azure Data lake

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-data-lake

How to decompress and read a .gz file which is in Azure data lake using c# asp.net

I have tried the following code but it results in an exception that.

> Exception: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\xxxxxx\filename'.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Obtain AAD token
        var creds = new ClientCredential(applicationId, clientSecret);
        var clientCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, creds).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // Create ADLS client object
        AdlsClient client = AdlsClient.CreateClient(adlsAccountFQDN, clientCreds);

        try
        {
            // Enumerate directory
            foreach (var entry in client.EnumerateDirectory("/Test/"))
            {
                try
                {
                    string filename =entry.Name;
                    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename), zippedStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(zippedStream))
                        {

                            // work with reader
                            reader.ReadLine();

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        catch (AdlsException e)
        {
            PrintAdlsException(e);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done. Press ENTER to continue ...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I would not expect a file located at azure data lake store in d:\. Can you post more code?

Comment: @PeterBons I have updated the question with more code.

Comment: Instead of entry.Name you probably want to use entry.FullName so it has the rest of the path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution.
Instead of **File.OpenRead(filename)** we should use **client.GetReadStream(entry.FullName)**.

The code is :

```
 foreach (var entry in client.EnumerateDirectory("/Test/"))
                {
                    StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
                    try
                    {
                        using (Stream fileStream = client.GetReadStream(entry.FullName), zippedStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(zippedStream))
                            {
                                string line;
                                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                                {
                                    lines.AppendLine(line);
                                    Console.WriteLine(lines);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [built-in extractors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621366.aspx) (Text, Csv, Tsv) now natively support gzipped files so you do not have to do anything special other than read them:

```
@data =
    EXTRACT Timestamp DateTime,
            Event string,
            Value int
    FROM "/input/input.csv.gz"
    USING Extractors.Csv();
```

This also works for custom extractors:

```
@data =
    EXTRACT Timestamp DateTime,
            Event string,
            Value int
    FROM "/input/input.csv.gz"
    USING  new USQLworking.MyExtractor();
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830459/how-to-read-encrypted-and-gzipped-blob-data-from-u-sql) for further note from Michael Rys.

Comment: He is not using u-SQL so I don't think this applies

Comment: Hi @PeterBons, I was thinking they are trying to roll their own method because they are not aware the built-in extractors natively deal with gzipped files, but yes of course, they could be attempting to create a custom extractor - however it's still the name; simply name the file `...something.gz`.